# How to execute a function when uwsgi is stopped

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

i am using flask and uwsgi.. At some point i need to know when uwsgi is stopped or when my app (Flask) object is destroyed and when it happens, execute a function.
Any ideas ??
Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the python atexit module or the uwsgi.atexit hook

Comment: nice it works, i used python atexit. I nevertheless have an additional question : it is said in the documentation that it wont work for signals not managed by python, what are these signals ??