# uWSGI run on exit

Tags: signals, uwsgi

I'm running a Flask app via uWSGI. I have some cleanup code that I need to run when my app exits (to shut down some external processes). I installed signal handlers for `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` to run the script using the python `signal` module. These work when I just run the app using `python` and hit for example `Ctrl+C`. However, for whatever reason, these don't get run when I do `/etc/init.d/uwsgi-emperor stop`, so they must be being bypassed by uWSGI code. What's the best way to get a function to be run on exit?

Answer (score 0):

Do not override UNIX signals in uWSGI workers, it is the path to an infinite stream of problems. As already suggested use python atexit module, the uwsgi.atexit python hook, or the more general uwsgi hooks (the ones you define from options, like --exec-as-user-atexit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569056/how-to-execute-a-function-when-uwsgi-is-stopped